# onchange event value changed programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's possible (using jQuery or native JS) catch a change event for an input whose value is changed programmatically?? I'm not able to fire the event when the value changes.

Thx for your time.

Comment: `$(<selector>).change();`

Comment: `I'm not able to fire the event when the value changes` How that?

Comment: If you change a value programmatically you'll need to also programmatically trigger the change event. In jQuery  you'd do something like `$("select").val("new value").trigger("change")`

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
$("input").change(function() {
    // listening for changes
});

// triger change event manually
$("input").change();
```

Comment: you are sure that this works when the value is changed programmatically??

Comment: Programmatically you have to trigger the change manually. Like this: `$("input").val("new value").change();`. There is no default way to track changes whos made on code side without manual trigger ...

Answer (score 1):

Most of the jQuery event handlers are also triggers.

For example, you can trigger the [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event as follows:

```
jQueryElement.change();
```

Or, you can use the jQuery [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function for any event:

```
jQueryElement.trigger("change");
```

With regular JavaScript (because jQuery isn't always necessary), use [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events):

```
jsElement.dispatchEvent("change");
```

<sub>Links to documentation pages are included.</sub>